# how to find special characters in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a code in Python and want to find vowels in a string. 
The code I have written is following....I tried different combinations for using For-Loop, but it throws two different errors;

1. 'int' object is not iterable,
2. string indices must be integers, not str.

how can I find all vowels in a line?

```
str1 = 'sator arepo tenet opera rotas'
vow1 = [str1[i] for i in str1 if  str1[i] is 'a' | 'e' | 'o']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about:

```
vowels = [ c for c in str1 if c in 'aeo' ]
```

You're getting errors because when you loop over a string, you loop over the *characters* in the string (not string *indices*) and because `'a' | 'e' | 'o'` doesn't make sense for strings -- (they don't support the `|` operator)

```
>>> str1 = 'sator arepo tenet opera rotas'
>>> vowels = [ c for c in str1 if c in 'aeo' ]
>>> print vowels
['a', 'o', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'a']
```

---

One final comment, you shouldn't use `is` to test for *equality*.  `is` tests for *identity*.  A simple test:

```
a = 565
b = 565
print a == b #True
print a is b #False (!)
```

The reason is because `a` and `b` reference *different objects that have the same value*.

Comment: Nice, but I'd probably use a set for the sought vowels:  sought_vowels=set('aeiouy'); c in sought_vowels.  "is" is a good idea for testing against None, but a bad idea for other tests.

Comment: @user1277476 -- For really small sets, it's unlikely that you'll see a significant difference between a `set` and the highly optimized string implementation -- A quick timeit shows differences less than 0.007 usec per loop.  In this case, I think it's Ok to use either `str.__contains__` or `set.__contains__` -- whichever OP finds more easy to read/understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
str1 = 'sator arepo tenet opera rotas'
i=0
vowl=''
for char in str1:
    if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':
          vowl=vowl+char+','

vowl=vowl[:-1]      
print (vowl)
```

The output is:

> a,o,a,e,o,e,e,o,e,a,o,a

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: str1 = 'sator arepo tenet opera rotas'
In [2]: filter(lambda x: x in 'aeiou', str1)
Out[2]: 'aoaeoeeoeaoa'
```